# Bing Azure search api

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, bing-api

I'm trying to connect to Bing search api and have not been able to get the code to work. I've googled the problem and no working code can be found.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


public class BSearch{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //--------------------------------------Bing search------------------------------
        String searchText = "barack";
        searchText = searchText.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        String accountKey="MYACCOUNTKEY";
        byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
        String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(
                    "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/Search/v1/Web?Query=%27" + searchText + "%27&$top=50&$format=json");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + accountKeyEnc);

     //  conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(output);

            System.out.println(output);
        }

        conn.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at BSearch.main(BSearch.java:30)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:385)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:326)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:231)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:196)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:268)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:380)
    ... 18 more
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen what looks like the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Java client needs the Bing's server public certificate to start the communication ([SSLHandshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_handshake)), you got the error because Bing's certificate is not in your default Java Keystore as a trusted certificate.

You can do the following:

- Get the Bing's certificate and import to your default Java Keystore for trusted certificates using [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html), your default Keystore named `cacerts` is usually located at `JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\`

> keytool -importcert -file bingcertificate.cer -keystore cacerts -alias "bingAlias"

- Create a dummy `SSLSocketFactory` to get a `SSLContext` which accepts any certificate and use it with your http connection object.

**Factory example**:

```
public class DummySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    public DummySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                //
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                //
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }
}
```

and then

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(new DummySSLSocketFactory());
```

- Create your own keystore, import the certificate and load it in your code to get a new factory

**Keystore example:**

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(new FileInputStream(new File("keystoreCompletePath")), "passwdKeyStore");
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(keyStore);
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
SSLSocketFactory sslFactory = ctx.getSocketFactory();
```

and then

```
HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory);
```