# how to make HTTPS calls using AsyncHttpClient?

Tags: android, networking, https, android-async-http

i was using `AsyncHttpClient` [link](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) for making http calls but now our server has migrated to HTTPS and I am getting exception `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate` .
Has anyone tried making https call using this library ?

initialization of AsyncHttpClient :-

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            PersistentCookieStore myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(
                    getActivity());
            // List<Cookie> cookies = myCookieStore.getCookies();
            myCookieStore.clear();
            // cookies = myCookieStore.getCookies();
            client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);

            client.get(loginUrl, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    super.onStart();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    super.onFinish();
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, JSONObject userInfo) {
                    super.onSuccess(statusCode, userInfo);

                    String errorMsg = null;
                    try {
                        errorMsg = userInfo.getString("error");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (errorMsg != null) {
                        errorMsg = getActivity().getResources().getString(
                                R.string.loginFailure)
                                + "\nError: " + errorMsg;
                        tvLoginFailure.setText(errorMsg);
                        tvLoginFailure.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    } else {
                        Subscriber.setEmail(email);
                        Subscriber.setPassword(password);
                        LoginUtility.saveUserInfo(getActivity(), userInfo);

                        if (Subscriber.getStatus().contentEquals("ACTIVE")) {
                            Intent intent;
                            if (MyApplication.ottMode) {
                                intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                        OTTMainScreen.class);

                            } else {
                                intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                        MainActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("SIGNEDIN", true);
                            }
                            if (MyApplication.ottMode) {
                                Utility.playSound(getActivity());
                            }
                            startActivity(intent);
                            getActivity().finish();

                        } else if (Subscriber.getStatus().contentEquals(
                                "SUSPENDED")) {
                            try {
                                String suspendedReason = userInfo
                                        .getString("suspendreason");
                                if (suspendedReason != null
                                        && suspendedReason
                                                .contentEquals("NO_SUBSCRIPTION")) {

                                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                                            .setIcon(
                                                    android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                                            .setTitle("Account Suspended")
                                            .setMessage(
                                                    "Your account doesn't have any active subscription. You need to subscribe to a Package before you can proceed.")
                                            .setPositiveButton(
                                                    "Subscribe",
                                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                        public void onClick(
                                                                DialogInterface dialog,
                                                                int which) {
                                                            recreatePackage();
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                                            .show();

                                } else {
                                    // TODO
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        } else if (Subscriber.getStatus().contentEquals("INIT")) {
                            // TODO
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode,
                        org.apache.http.Header[] headers, String responseBody,
                        Throwable e) {
                    super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseBody, e);
                    String msg = getActivity().getResources().getString(
                            R.string.loginFailure)
                            + "\nError: " + responseBody;
                    tvLoginFailure.setText(msg);
                    tvLoginFailure.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Post your AsyncHttpClient initialization code, please.

Comment: similar solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42805652/setup-asynchttpclient-to-use-https

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need import the public server certificate into your default keystore, or if you are not interested in the authentication of your client you can initialize the `AsyncHttpClient` with

```
AsyncHttpClient asycnHttpClient = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);
```

but this trick is not secure because use a custom [SSLSocketFactory](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/MySSLSocketFactory.java) implementation whos omit the SSL certificate validation, take a look at the [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.java) source code.

More information about SSLSocketFactory at https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html

Comment: "You need import the public server certificate into your default keystore" can u give some links for that ?

Comment: You're welcome :), a good example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706026/bing-azure-search-api/20789379#20789379

Comment: SSLSocketFactory is deprecated. https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory; Also, I tried the above code snippet and that did not work either.

Answer (score 11):

you can also solve this problem, with adding this 1 line.

```
asyncHttpClient.setSSLSocketFactory(MySSLSocketFactory.getFixedSocketFactory());
```

Comment: It is important to mention, when using MySSLSocketFactory: "Warning! This omits SSL certificate validation on every device, use with caution."

Comment: This is a better solution than the previous above it. But it did not solve my issue unfortunately. I really like asyncHttpClient but this is now a blocker for me. Only alternative is for me to make sure the server cert is in my keystore. The call still initiates an SSL handshake and then it fails. I used the okHttp code generated by Postman, for the SAME https call, and it works. Go figure!!!!

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple http client that calls https service:

```
import android.util.Log;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

/**
 */
public class HttpSimpleClient {

    private static final String TAG = HttpSimpleClient.class.getSimpleName();

    private static HttpSimpleClient instance;

    private HttpSimpleClient(){}

    public static HttpSimpleClient instance(){
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = new HttpSimpleClient();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public <T> T post(URL url,
                      List<NameValuePair> header,
                      List<NameValuePair> parameter,
                      ResponseHandler<T> responseHandler) throws IOException {
        return post(url, header, parameter, responseHandler, null, null);
    }

    public <T> T post(URL url,
                     List<NameValuePair> header,
                     List<NameValuePair> parameter,
                     ResponseHandler<T> responseHandler,
                     AuthScope proxy,
                     UsernamePasswordCredentials proxyUser) throws IOException {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url.toString());

        if (header!=null) {
            for (NameValuePair head : header){
                request.setHeader(head.getName(), head.getValue());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Aggiunti header: "+ header.size());

        } else {
            // Header di default
            request.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.setHeader("User-Agent", System.getProperty("http.agent"));
            Log.d(TAG, "Aggiunti header di defautl");
        }

        if (parameter!=null) {
            request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameter, HTTP.UTF_8));
            Log.d(TAG, "Aggiunti parametri: "+ parameter.size());
        }


        if (proxy!=null) {
            if (proxyUser!=null) {
                ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(proxy, proxyUser);

            } else {
                // TODO gestire proxy senza credenziali
                ((AbstractHttpClient) httpClient).getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(proxy, null);

            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Impostato Proxy per la connessione");
        }
        return httpClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
    }


    public static String httpResponseToString(HttpResponse httpResponse, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
        InputStream content = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

        int numRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        ByteArrayOutputStream outString = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try{
            while ((numRead = content.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outString.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
            }
        } finally {
            content.close();
        }
        return new String(outString.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

And i use it in a AsyncTask:

```
response = HttpSimpleClient.instance().post(
                    getServiceURL(), // HTTPS url
                    mHeader, // List<NameValuePair>
                    mParameter, // List<NameValuePair>
                    getResponseHandler() // org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler
            );
```

Tested on Android api>=10

Comment: I have to use GET method !!

Comment: HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toString()); //url with params
and not HttpPost

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code:

```
private Map<String, String> mParams;

public void sendata(View v) throws JSONException {
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtusername);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);

    final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("password", password.getText());
    j.put("username", username.getText());
    j.put("Deviceid", 123456789);
    j.put("RoleId", 1);
    String url = Url;
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    params.put("json", j.toString());
    client.post(url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {
            pDialog.hide();
            JSONObject jsnObjct;
            try {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response
                        .toString()).nextValue();
                JSONObject json2 = json.getJSONObject("Data");
                JSONArray test = (JSONArray) json2
                        .getJSONArray("PatientAllergies");
                for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
                    json = test.getJSONObject(i);
                    System.out.print(json.getString("PatientId"));
                    System.out.print(json.getString("Id"));
                    System.out.print(json.getString("AllergyName"));
                    System.out.print(json.getString("Reaction"));
                    System.out.print(json.getString("OnSetDate"));
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res,
                Throwable t) {
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    });

}
JSONObject jsonObject;

private void parsejson(JSONObject response) {

    try {
        jsonObject = response;
        System.out.print(response.toString());
        JSONObject jsnObjct = jsonObject.getJSONObject("Data");
        System.out.print(jsonObject.toString());
        jsnObjct = jsnObjct.getJSONObject("PhysicianDetail");

        System.out.print(jsnObjct.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```