# Setup AsyncHttpClient to use HTTPS

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2, asynchttpclient

I am using `com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9` for my request to server. It was working fine until I SSL/TLS is required in my server. So I need to modify my `AsyncHTTPClient` to use HTTPS in all URLs.

I checked this similar [how to make HTTPS calls using AsyncHttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833804/how-to-make-https-calls-using-asynchttpclient) but did not provide clear solution to the problem. The accepted solution was not secure as well because of this warning from the library itself:

> Warning! This omits SSL certificate validation on every device, use
>   with caution.

So I went on and check other solutions. I ended up following the recommendation from: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html. Thus, I have something similar to this:

```
// Load CAs from an InputStream
// (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
// From https://www.washington.edu/itconnect/security/ca/load-der.crt
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}

// Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

// Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
tmf.init(keyStore);

// Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// Get SocketFactory from our SSLContext
//
//      !!!PROBLEM IS HERE!!!
//   
javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
```

As you can see in the last line, it gives an `SSLSocketFactory` from `javax.net.ssl` package. However the `AsyncHTTPClient` instance requires

`asyncHTTPClient.setSSLSocketFactory(cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory)`

**EDIT:**

My server is using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Have you found a good solution? I'm a bit lost

Comment: looks like @Prerak's solution below works. I am gonna add my own version too. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.java#L760), `setSSLFactory` requires an object of `SSLFactory`, so you can create your own `MySSLFactory` class. In the below example I have renamed it to `MyCustomSSLFactory`. The code for **SSL Validaton** is in the method `checkServerTrusted` of `X509TrustManager`. You can modify it as per your need if needed.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.HttpVersion;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ClientConnectionManager;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.scheme.SchemeRegistry;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.params.BasicHttpParams;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.params.HttpParams;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.params.HttpProtocolParams;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.protocol.HTTP;


/**
 * Created by prerak on 15/03/2017.
 */

public class MyCustomSSLFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

    /**
     * Creates a new SSL Socket Factory with the given KeyStore.
     *
     * @param truststore A KeyStore to create the SSL Socket Factory in context of
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException  NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws KeyManagementException    KeyManagementException
     * @throws KeyStoreException         KeyStoreException
     * @throws UnrecoverableKeyException UnrecoverableKeyException
     */
    public MyCustomSSLFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
        super(truststore);

        X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                try {
                    chain[0].checkValidity();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new CertificateException("Certificate not valid or trusted.");
                }
            }

            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }
        };

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
    }

    /**
     * Gets a KeyStore containing the Certificate
     *
     * @param cert InputStream of the Certificate
     * @return KeyStore
     */
    public static KeyStore getKeystoreOfCA(InputStream cert) {

        // Load CAs from an InputStream
        InputStream caInput = null;
        Certificate ca = null;
        try {
            CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            caInput = new BufferedInputStream(cert);
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
        } catch (CertificateException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (caInput != null) {
                    caInput.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = null;
        try {
            keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
            keyStore.load(null, null);
            keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyStore;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a Default KeyStore
     *
     * @return KeyStore
     */
    public static KeyStore getKeystore() {
        KeyStore trustStore = null;
        try {
            trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
        return trustStore;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a SSlSocketFactory which trusts all certificates
     *
     * @return SSLSocketFactory
     */
    public static SSLSocketFactory getFixedSocketFactory() {
        SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;
        try {
            socketFactory = new MyCustomSSLFactory(getKeystore());
            socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            socketFactory = SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
        }
        return socketFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a DefaultHttpClient which trusts a set of certificates specified by the KeyStore
     *
     * @param keyStore custom provided KeyStore instance
     * @return DefaultHttpClient
     */
    public static DefaultHttpClient getNewHttpClient(KeyStore keyStore) {

        try {
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MyCustomSSLFactory(keyStore);
            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
    }

    /**
     * Makes HttpsURLConnection trusts a set of certificates specified by the KeyStore
     */
    public void fixHttpsURLConnection() {
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
    }
}
```

Now you can initialise an object of `MyCustomSSLSocketFactory` by passing your custom `KeyStore` to it.

```
MyCustomSSLFactory socketFactory = new MyCustomSSLFactory(keyStore);
```

And now you can set the socket factory as:

```
asyncHTTPClient.setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
```

Comment: Hey @Prerak Sola, I also did this approach. It worked but the issue of ***"Warning! This omits SSL certificate validation on every device, use with caution"*** persists on this one as we are using the `MySSLSocketFactory` class from `com.loopj.android.http`.

Comment: hi @Prerak, can you please tell me whats the difference between your code and com.loopj.android.http.MySSLSocketFactory? If you would follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833804/how-to-make-https-calls-using-asynchttpclient, this would lead to `Warning! This omits SSL certificate validation on every device, use with caution.`

Comment: The difference is in the implementation of `X509TrustManager`. By default the method `checkServerTrusted` returns null which leads to the warning that you mentioned. But in the answer that I have posted, that method has been modified to verify the server's identity.

Comment: looks like your solution works. i am gonna add my own solution in the answers section too.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have a self signed certificate on your server, I dont have a code that does it using com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9, but I can give you code that uses URLConnection and which loads crt file (my.server.net.crt) from assets folder.:

```
  public static HttpsURLConnection connectSelfSignedHttps(Context ctx, String surl) throws CertificateException, IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {

    // Load CAs from an InputStream
    // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    // 
    InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(ctx.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("my.server.net.crt"));
    Certificate ca;
    try {
      ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
      //System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
    } finally {
      caInput.close();
    }

    // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
    String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null, null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

    // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
    URL url = new URL(surl);
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
        (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

    return urlConnection;
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I am using a self-signed certificate. Your code is similar to mine. I am looking for an answer that uses com.loopj.android:android-async-http. Thanks for the time to share your solution. =)

Answer (score 0):

you can use @Prerak's solution. Looks like that solution works. This is my own version. It is similar to @Prerak's but a shorter constructor:

```
public CustomSSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    super(truststore);

    // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
    String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(truststore);

    // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
    sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
}
```